# Have I forgotten anything?

Tags: touring, preparation

Doing a London - Brighton run on Saturday morning, so far in the backpack I will have :

Spare inner tubes,
Jet pump,
Multi tool kit,
Tyre levers,
Gel bars,
Fluids,
Cash & Card incase,

Am I going over the top taking a spare chain? Do I need anything else?

By the way I'm doing this on a modified MTB 
29" × 2.1 are now 700 × 38,
Grips are now more ergonomic with slight bar ends

So more towards a hybrid but with MTB gearing.

Comment: I like to have a short length of chain -- maybe 10-15 links.  And a chain tool, of course.

Comment: That route looks to be only 50 miles. That stuff you should be able to fit all in a saddle bag rather than a backpack, would make for more comfortable riding.

Comment: Spare chain is probably over the top unless you don't have some quick links in your saddle bag already by the time you start (see if LBS has some in your size). If a chain snaps at one pin, you can just drive out the other pin from the outer link and put the quick link in its place.

Comment: Phone and helmet

Comment: Water and a rain jacket, some means of navigating

Comment: 2-3 links of chain and quick links wouldn't be completely ridiculous, although that's a short ride to have that level of preparation. A couple of zip ties and a meter of gorilla tape wound around your pump can be useful fix-it materials.

Comment: I usually stuff in a minimal first-aid kit:  some disinfectant wipes, a tube of antibiotic ointment, 2 or 3 sticking plasters, a gauze pad and a tiny roll of tape.

Comment: +1 @DavidW hadn't even thought of first aid

Comment: @Chris H I'll have fluids so water is covered, hadn't considered a light rain jacket but there's room so one can go in

Comment: @Swifty are you suggesting I take a spare helmet?

Comment: Does anyone want to digest all this into an answer

Comment: @DanK lol no, not a spare, just the one. I was putting down slightly obvious but 'essential' items which weren't listed, for the sake of listing them; If you were making a checklist to ensure you didn't forget anything, they'd want to go on it. If you need to travel by car or train etc for example before the ride. if you ride from your front door this shouldn't be a probem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have said you're planning on taking: Spare inner tubes, Jet pump, Multi tool kit, Tyre levers, Gel bars, Fluids, Cash & Card

So you've covered flat tyres, energy, hydration and money.

Other suggested repair items:  chain tool, quick links, spoke tool, zip ties, strong tape.

Unforeseen circumstances:  mobile telephone/cellphone, emergency contact information, rain jacket, hat/gloves

First aid:  some disinfectant wipes, a tube of antibiotic ointment, 2 or 3 sticking plasters, a gauze pad and a tiny roll of tape.  Tweezers.

Daytime Running Lights - You haven't mentioned time of day or season, so consider DRLs for daytime riding and if there's a risk of being caught by sunset. (Personally I use DRLs all the time, and keep some other lights for night time.)

Lock - Is there a chance you'll leave your bike unattended? A small bike lock might help if you choose to duck into a shop or cafe.

Even if you cover up or apply before you leave, a small tube of sunscreen will allow you to reapply on your face, ears, backs of your hands or any other exposed skin.  A number of people I ride with also use a SPF chapstick.

Comment: Note that I only usually carry 1 spare tube, but also a set of "glueless" patches; they've worked really well for me so far.

Comment: You didn't mention if you are alone or in a group. If alone Emergency Contact Information Card. Leave a route map with some one at home along with your planned departure and arrival time